# Where is php7.0-fpm.sock located

Tags: php, nginx, unix-socket

I have a simple project with directory structure

I am setting up nginx config for my drupal site, and for the `fastcgi_pass` I have been using `127.0.0.1:9000` but I want to use a unix socket as suggested in this conf:

```
 # PHP 7 socket location.
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

but I can't find `php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`

I have the following path in my centos distro

```
/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
```

Answer (score 27):

Check the **php-fpm** config where the socket will be created with:

`$ cat /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

Look for `listen`, for example:

`listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`

**php-fpm** creates the socket file *after* you started the process.

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm stop
sudo service php7.0-fpm start
```

Check the directory if socket file was created:

`$ cd /run/php && ls -la`

Comment: Where is located in ubutnu?

Comment: I only see php7.0-fpm.pid file

Comment: I am running several ubuntus. Default path (I've never changed this): /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock. But again it is depending on the config value and this file should be created if php-fpm is starte.

Comment: But there is only one file php7.0-fpm.pid

Comment: Again: the config tells, where to place the socket file. It should be present (created by service), when the php-fpm "service" is running.

Comment: Config is showing as /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock  but there is no file

Comment: lol i can understand why Ben gave up! XD yasar did you come right?

Comment: I also only have `php7.0-fpm.pid` (tried running `sudo service php7.0-fpm start`)

Answer (score 21):

First check if `php-fpm` is running on your system, for doing this you could use `pgrep` for example:

```
# pgrep -fa php-fpm
5666 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
5667 php-fpm: pool www
5668 php-fpm: pool www
5669 php-fpm: pool www
5670 php-fpm: pool www
5671 php-fpm: pool www
```

In this case, it shows is up and running and using the configuration file `/etc/php-fpm.conf`.  Before checking the configuration file and trying to check for the `listen =` directive you could quickly look into [`/proc/net/unix`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183140/53084) for example:

```
# grep php /proc/net/unix
```

Which may return something like:

```
ffff8800bfb2f400: 00000002 00000000 00010000 0001 01 28561 /tmp/php-fpm.sock
```

In this case, it shows that the path for the php-fpm socket is located in `/tmp/php-fpm.sock` the one could be verified by checking the conf in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` in this case being: `listen= /tmp/php-fpm.sock`

In case you don't get any result and `php-fpm` is up and running, by checking the configuration you may find that is using the defaults by listing on a TCP socket:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Something you could change to listen on a Unix socket like your suggested conf:

```
listen = /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

In some Linux distros normally this is used:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

After modifying your configuration don't forget to restart the services `systemctl restart php-fpm`. To check that the socket has been created you could do:

```
$ file /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

If socket exists if should print out something like this:

```
/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock: socket
```

Comment: Just to get it right and clear, what is the difference to the other answer? Ok, different paths in centOS. But what else? I thought, I've read somewhere, that it is not recommended to point the socket to /tmp because of security reasons.

Comment: @BenRoob mainly focus on finding the location of the socket on a running system something that can be useful also when debugging

Comment: @BenRoob The currently top voted answer fails to address the case when the configuration uses IP:PORT over a socket, in which case the file obviously would not exist.

Comment: Much better than accepted, millions thanks :) "sudo vim /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf" and got "listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock" so added "fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;" in nginx instead "fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock"

Answer (score 2):

you can see it by running

```
$ ss --unix |grep 'php'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that an older libpcre3 is installed and satisfies the dependency in the php7.0 package, but only the newer library package provides pcre_jit_stack_free.

If this is the case, do an apt-get install libpcre3, and you’re good to go.

Ref.: https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/372

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
cat /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf | grep 'listen ='
```

> **Output example:** listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock

Or for universal php vesions:

```
cat /etc/php/$(php -r "echo PHP_VERSION;" | grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "7.\d+")/fpm/pool.d/www.conf | grep 'listen ='
```